# Add contour lines and clabel in 2D contour

Tags: python

3D surface and 2D contour map

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)

    # X, Y value

    X = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.25)
    Y = np.arange(-4, 4, 0.25)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    R = np.sqrt(X \*\* 2 + Y \*\* 2)

    # height value

    Z = np.sin(R)

    # draw surface plot

    surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow')

    # add colorbar

    fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.75)

    # projecting the contour with an offset

    ax.contourf(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-2, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

    # match the lower bound of zlim to the offset

    ax.set_zlim(-2, 2)

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIeSb.png)
[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiYht.png)

I want to draw the same contour lines and comment as in Figure 1 in the 3D surface and 2D contour map of Figure 2.

Comment: take a look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/contour3d.html 
 and https://coderslegacy.com/python/3d-contour-plots-matplotlib/